# strange issue with return of method

Tags: php

I can seem to get the method return me an array. I can get the var_dump just before the return in myRecursiveFunction at

```
if($return){
            var_dump($myArray);
            return $myArray;
        }
```

but in the calling function my var_dump is empty....not sure what am I doing wrong

```
private function myCallingFunction(){

            $x = $this->myRecursiveFunction();
var_dump($x);

    }

private function myRecursiveFunction($next = null, $recursion = false, $myArray = array())
{
    $return = false;
    if (!$recursion) {

        $result = json_decode($this->getMyResults);
        $myArray = $result->myResults;
        if ($result->getMore) {
            $this->myRecursiveFunction($result->getMore, true, $myArray);
            $return = false;
        }else{
            $return = true;
        }
    } else {
        $result = json_decode($this->getMyResults);
        $myArray = array_merge($myArray,$result->myResults);
        if ($result->getMore) {
            $this->myRecursiveFunction($result->getMore, true, $myArray);
            $return = false;
        }else{
            $return = true;
        }
    }
    if($return){
        var_dump($myArray);
        return $myArray;
    }

}
```

Comment: may b you are getting false as return..!

Comment: no because it gives me var_dump before return

Answer (score 0):

just had to do this

```
return $this->myRecursiveFunction($result->getMore, true, $myArray);
```